# Prove that $\Bbb R^2 - \{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \Bbb R$.

Tags: general-topology

No idea where to even begin. There is a hint: this requires construction of an explicit function.

Comment: To make drawings easier, you can always use $B(0,1)$ instead of $\Bbb R^2$ and $(0,1)$ instead of $\Bbb R$. Then the homeomorphism should be clear: pull from the tiny hole in $B(0,1)$ outwards, while pulling from (nonexistent) the boundary of $B(0,1)$ to get a cylinder with no "endpoint" circles.

Comment: Can I assume that R^2 \{0} and S^1 x R are continuous or is that an additional part I have to prove with U open in Y?

Comment: Careful: functions may or not be continuous; continuity does not apply to spaces.

Comment: This question is an exercise in a well-known textbook. I wish people would stop posting questions from textbooks on sites like this. It makes it annoyingly difficult to create homework for my students, knowing that they can simply google the exact statement of the question and immediately find an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**: The plane minus the origin can be written as

$$\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\} = \{(r \cos{t}, r \sin{t}) : 0 < r < \infty, 0 \le t < 2\pi\}$$

Do you see how this looks like a circle cross a line?

Comment: This is far more than a hint. You just can't resist giving answers rather than hints!

Comment: And would S1 x R just look like a cylinder that keeps going as the real line keeps going?

Comment: You have a copy of circles indexed by the Reals\{0}. For every r in Reals\{0}, take a circle of radius r centered at the origin.

Answer (score 7):

HINTS: Use polar coordinates for $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ and $S^1$.

- For each $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ the ray $\{\langle r,\theta\rangle:r>0\}$ corresponds to the line $\{\langle 1,\theta\rangle\}\times\Bbb R$.
- The map $$\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}x-1,&\text{if }x\ge 1\\\\1-\dfrac1x,&\text{if }0<x<1\end{cases}$$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: One might simply use $x-\frac1x$ for $0\lt x\lt\infty$.