# Compute explicitly a fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I want to compute the $\pi_1(X)$ where
$$X=\mathbb{R}^2-(([-1,1]\times \{0\})\cup (\{0\}\times [-1,1]))$$
my only tools at the moment are the basic definitions and the fundamental group of a circle, I think this should be the same group $\mathbb{Z}$ but I don't know how to calculate it explicitly.

Comment: Do you mean $[-1,1]$?  Remember that the fundamental group is a homotopy invariant, so if two spaces are homotopy equivalent, then they have the same fundamental group.

Comment: I am trying to follow a book to study this subject by myself, and that concept appears later so I tink I am not suposed to use it yet.

Comment: $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^2-(0,0).$

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: Is a small book written by a professor in my university "Topología algebraica, Vicente Muñoz"

Comment: Since $X$ is homotopy-equivalent to $S^1$, an explicit calculation--without utilizing helper theorems--would be fairly difficult for a beginning student.  Are you sure you're not supposed to rely on other results?  Perhaps "explicit" means: "Identify an explicit generator for the group"?

Comment: where can I find an explanation for what $\mathbb{R}^2-(([-1,1]\times 0)\cup (0\times [-1,1]))$ would mean ?

Comment: Well I would be glad if I really need more concepts to solve it because I was getting frustrated. I will ask the author in case this is an errate.

Comment: would be possible to show that $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$?

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^2-(0,0).$ To see this retract the $(([−1,1]×{0})∪({0}×[−1,1]))$ to the origin. Then consider loops that contain the origin and loops that do not contain the origin.

Answer (score 0):

The space X in questions is homotopy equivalent to $R^{2}\setminus (0,0)$ because you can immage to extend its hole in the two coordinate direction.

Now $\pi_{1}(X)\cong \pi_{1}(R^{2}\setminus (0,0))$ and the last one is $\mathbb{Z}$ because $R^{2}\setminus (0,0)\cong \mathbb{R}\times S^{1}$ 
(for example see this: [Prove that $\Bbb R^2 - \{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \Bbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551087/prove-that-bbb-r2-0-is-homeomorphic-to-s1-times-bbb-r) ).

Finally $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{R}\times S^{1})\cong \pi_{1}(\mathbb{R})\times \pi_{1}(S^{1}) \cong 0\times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The OP says in the comments that they're not allowed to use the fact that fundamental group is a homotopy invariant.